# Odd behaviour when doing LIKE with wildcards searching for backslash in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've encountered a very unusual problem with MySQL, involving backslashes. Basically when I do a wildcard match with LIKE for \n which is in the database as text rather than an actual newline, it will only return a match if I have just a right hand wildcard:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `tmptest` 
WHERE  `a` LIKE  '\\\\n%'
```

Now, if I query like this, it will not return anything:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `tmptest` 
WHERE `a` LIKE '%\\\\n%'
```

As you can see from the data I have in the table both queries should be matching. I'm not sure if it's something that I'm missing, or I'm incorrectly escaping the newline but it doesn't make sense for the first query to work and the second not.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmptest` (
`a` varchar(22) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample data:**

```
INSERT INTO `tmptest` (`a`) VALUES
('\\n'),
('\\n\\ndfsdfsdfs\\n');
```

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Comment: Odd, working fine for me. What mysql version are you using?

Comment: +1, Interesting problem. I praise you for including correct information on how to create the structure and insert sample data. Great first post.

Comment: I replicated it here. Version: mysqld  Ver 5.1.49-log for suse-linux-gnu on i686 (SUSE MySQL RPM)

Comment: I was unable to replicate on MySQL 5.5.9 (Windows XP)

Comment: Good to hear it's not just me then! I'm on 5.1.54 (Plesk/Cent OS) but also can reproduce on my Mac with MAMP (MySQL 5.5.9). Sounds like an upgrade may be required based on Karolis' and Jim's responses.

Comment: @Adam I was a little incorrect. I was unable to reproduce the problem using this: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT '\\n\\ndfsdfsdfs\\n' a) x WHERE a LIKE '%\\\\n%'`. But when I tried to create real tables using sample data you provided then I got the same result as yours. Very strange.

Comment: Why not put MySQL into ANSI mode? Then no escaping of backslashes is needed in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me with **6** backslashes when using the left side wildcard:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tmptest` WHERE `a` LIKE '%\\\\\\n%';
+-----------------+
| a               |
+-----------------+
| \n              |
| \n\ndfsdfsdfs\n |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Using mysqld Ver 5.1.49**

---

@Karolis as far as i understand the expression for the `LIKE` operator should be parsed twice, hence `\\\\` turns into `\` when used with LIKE.

But how to explain this (using the expression "back\slash"):

`SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%back\\\\slash%';` -> TRUE (normal behaviour)

`SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%back\\\\\slash%';` -> TRUE (5 backslashes?)

`SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%back\\\\\\slash%';` -> TRUE (6 backslashes?)

`SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%back\\\\\\\slash%';` -> TRUE (7 backslashes?)

`SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%back\\\\\\\\slash%';` -> FALSE (normal behaviour, I guess..)

Nevertheless if searching only for the "\":

`mysql> SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%\\\\%';` --> FALSE (but should work)

`mysql> SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%\\\\\%';` --> TRUE (5 backslashes)

`mysql> SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%\\\\\\%';` --> TRUE (6 backslashes)

`mysql> SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%\\\\\\\%';` --> FALSE (7 backslashes)

For this particular question, one could use a different escape character `|` and bypass the problem altogether (if no `|` character occurs):

`mysql> SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%\\%' ESCAPE '|';`  --> TRUE

So maybe some mysql guru out there can explain this. I simply can't. also tested with mysql **5.1.53** on a different machine. Same behaviour was observed. As i started by commenting, its a rather interesting question.

Comment: @Qsp Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: Further to this, for anyone who reads this in future and is trying to use this in a PHP script, the query will need to be in apostrophes rather than quotes and, it will need 12 backslashes.

Comment: @Karolis, no. i can't understand the reason behind it. could you tell us what version of mysql you are using?

Comment: @Adam, I think you could also use the [PHP addslashes](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) function to prepare your query.

Comment: @Qsp I think when a slash is before a character which has no special meaning then slash is omitted. As you mentioned, the string is parsed twice, so slashes can be omitted twice too. Perhaps this is why it returns true for 5, 6 and 7 slashes. But the coolest part is that results differs when we use strings as constants and when we use the same data from tables. I get right results using the former way, but wrong results otherwise. For me this returns TRUE: `SELECT 'back\\slash' LIKE '%\\\\%'`, but this returns FALSE: `SELECT a LIKE '%\\\\%' FROM tmptest` (with the same data in column).

Comment: @Qsp As I mentioned in comment below the question, my MySQL version is 5.5.9 (Windows XP).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the QSP answer (As I thanks him for saving my day).

I would say use **5** blackslashes.
I don't understand why like QSP and Karolis, but if you replace 1 slash by 5 slaches in mySQL (or 10 in php), it still work as QSP say.

**BUT** the good thing, is if you replace '\\' by 12 backslashes (or 24 in php) as QSP suggest, it won't work. But if replace it by 10 backslashes (or 20 in php) it will still work.

I hope that can help someone as QSP answer is already accepted.

**EDIT :**
It work fine if you do :
%\\\\\%
%\\\\\\\\\\%
%k\\\\\\\\\\s%
%\\\\\\\\\\s%
%k\\\\\s% (if only 1 slash like back\slash)
But it doesn't work if you do :
%k\\\\\\\\\\%
%k\\\\\%
%\\\\\s%
I will continue to look why.